# PNG files are not being displayed in IE and Vista's Sidebar

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer

I am using Windows Vista.

I was just visiting a website and found some "missing" images boxes on webpages. And, I could see this for many of the websites I visited. Then I realised that only a certain type of image files are not being displayed, which is PNG. I restarted my computer and noticed that 2 of the sidebar gadgets were missing background images.

The websites with "missing" images are working fine in Firefox though. So its a problem related to IE and some of the Windows files.

Any ideas how do I get PNGs working in my IE and Sidebar etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a real answer, but I've found two promising sites during my search, a [KB Entry](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B283807&x=7&y=8) and [this](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/202/1/PNG-images-are-not-displayed-on-Web-sites-in-Internet-Explorer.html).

Comment: regarding your first link .. only png images/pictures are not being displayed others are ok. I just looked at the other link as well, but I was not sure if I should make changes to registry via a file supplied by an "unknown" source. thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: Reg files are just text files, you can open them and check what they do.